Referencing a .Net Standard 2.0 assembly in a .Net Framework 4.8 projects generates build error
In a .NET Standard 2.0 assembly, I have a function to write to the eventlog:
public static void WriteEventLog(string Source, string Message, EventLogEntryType EvType)

The enum EventLogEntryType is referenced in nuget System.Diagnostics.EventLog 8.0.0. The assembly builds without errors.
But when I reference the assembly in another class library which is on .NET 4.8 and try to call this function, I get this build error:

Error CS0012
The type 'EventLogEntryType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

So I tried to reference System.Diagnostics.EventLog 8.0.0 also in in the .NET 4.8 library, but it doesn't help. I still get the same error.
Am I doing something wrong? How can I solve this?
It looks like the compiler uses EventLogEntryType from assembly System, Version 4.0.0 and not the EventLogEntryType from System.Diagnostics.EventLog 8.0.0.
As requested csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <RootNamespace>xx.yyy.zzz</RootNamespace>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenXMLSDK-MOT" Version="2.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="ncalc" Version="1.3.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Packaging" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.10.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Federation" Version="4.10.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Former comment deleted ... if I read it correctly, nuget gallery says it should be fine?

Can you add the csproj of your netstandard library? I have a suspicion.

I cannot reproduce the error, make sure the alias property of the referenced nuget package is global, then clean & rebuild.

Please post the csproj, at least the Reference and PackageReference elements of both projects. the compiler uses EventLogEntryType from assembly System, Version 4.0.0 yes, as it should, and that should work fine. When .NET Standard libraries need to call runtime types they use a shim that gets mapped to the correct runtime type. Both the .NET Standard library and .NET Framework/.NET Core applications must use the same Standard package so they can use the same shim

@Fildor i included the csproj in the question


There's no reference to System.Diagnostics.EventLog anywhere in the project file. It's an indirect dependency of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog though 2) What about the .NET Framework 4.8 project? Did you add Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog or System.Diagnostics.EventLog? Do you have any assembly reference instead of package reference to System.Diagnostics.EventLog ?


Thank you all for your help. I made a mistake. I referenced Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog. The correct reference is System.Diagnostics.EventLog

Reference System.Diagnostics.EventLog instead Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog works.
